# How to check if $2$ is a square $\mod 3$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, square-numbers, quadratic-residues

I don't think I can use the Legendre or Jacobi symbol here because $2$ is an even prime. I'm not sure I've learned methods to deal with $2$ even though I know how to use quadratic reciprocity, it only works with odd numbers I think.

Comment: $0^2\equiv0\pmod3$, $1^2\equiv1\pmod3$, $2^2\equiv1\pmod3$

Comment: Maybe you're looking for a method for deciding whether $2$ is a square mod $p$, where $p$ is an arbitrary odd prime, because the $p=3$ case is just trivial.

Comment: I see a pattern that every square is either $0$ or $1$ $\mod 3$, but I don't know how to prove that every square number is either $0$ or $1$ $\mod 3$.

Comment: @eyes This follows easily by modular arithmetic, as in egreg's first comment. Before studying advanced results such as quadratic reciprocity, one should be sure to have mastered basic modular arithmetic / congruences, Else one will have a very difficult time comprehending more advanced results.

Comment: @BillDubuque I didn't know, as this is a first course in number theory (and the only number theory course we have in our college) and he started the course with quadratic reciprocity

Comment: That's quite unusual.Attempting to understand quadratic reciprocity without mastering basic modular arithmetic or congruences is an extreme example of trying to run before one learns how to walk!

Comment: @BillDubuque The professor is quite brilliant, so I guess he assumed modular arithmetic and congruences were too trivial/obvious to teach.

Comment: In any case, I strongly recommend that you master such before tackling more advanced topics. There are many answers here that will aid learning: simply type "mod" in the site search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a more general context $2$ is a square mod $p$ where $p$ is an odd prime if and only if :

$$\begin{pmatrix}2\\p\end{pmatrix}=(-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}}\text{ is } 1$$

In your case, because $3^2-1=9-1=8$ the answer is no.

Comment: $2$ is a square mod $p$ when $p=2$ (ducks)

Comment: I wanted my answer to be complete and I forgot to mention this case... I am confused, thank you...

Answer (score 2):

$0^2 = 0 \equiv 0 \pmod3$

$1^2 = 1 \equiv 1 \pmod3$

$2^2 = 4 \equiv 1 \pmod3$

So, no.

Comment: I don't see how this proves that $2$ is not a square ($\mod 3$). What is the justification for not having to check every square number $\mod 3$?

Comment: @EYES, what other numbers exist mod 3? 0,1, and 2 are the only numbers here.

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs $(3n+k)^2 = 3(3n^2+2k)+k^2 \equiv k^2 \pmod3$ so you do not have to look at any more

Comment: Yes, but how do you know that maybe some arbitrarily large square will not equal to $2 \mod 3$?

Comment: @EYES Prove that multiplication is well-defined mod n: if $n\mid (a-b)$ and $n\mid (c-d)$ then $n\mid (ac-bd)$.

Comment: What does $(3n + k)^2$ represent?

Comment: @ᴇʏᴇs $(3n + k)^2$ represents the square of a number $k$ more than a multiple of $3$.  Modulo $3$ this square is equivalent to $k^2$, as I have shown in my comment, and $k^2$  is equivalent to $0$ or $1$ as I have shown in my answer.

Comment: So if the square of $k$ more than a multiple of $3$ is congruent to $k^2 \mod 3$, doesn't that just mean every integer greater than $3$ that is squared is just a square number greater than $3$ (which doesn't give us anything)? e.g. $(3(1) + 5)^2 \equiv 25 \mod 3$, and $25 \equiv 1 \mod 3$ but if $k$ was some arbitrarily large integer, we would still have to check if that square was not $2 \mod 3$ or not manually

Comment: No, $k$ is either $0, 1, 2$. Haven't you learned the division algorithm?

Comment: No, we haven't covered the division algorithm but I can learn try to learn it.

Comment: If you wanted to say $k$ was $3$ like $3n + 3$, for example, then I could just call that number $3(n+1) + 0$ and so Henry's argument still applies. If you wanted to tell me that $k$ was $43$, as in $3n + 43$, then I could just write $3(n+14) + 1$. The only possible remainders when dividing by $3$ are $0,1,2$. The fact is that every single integer is of the form $3n$, $3n + 1$, or $3n + 2$. There are no other possibilities.

Comment: What Henry has shown you is that no matter what integer you have, its square is congruent to the square of its remainder when divided by $3$ (which is either $0,1,2$ ) and you have already evaluated the squares of $0,1,2$.

Comment: Is this possible in general for $\mod n$ where $n$ is any positive integer?

Comment: Is it possible, yes. But if it was mod 437, you probably wouldn't want to check every single congruence class.